# "Cannot find module 'react'" and "tsconfig.json not found"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, npm, eslint

I'm trying to build a workspace based application with NodeJS and React using TypeScript. I did configured a `package.json` on the root directory and used the workspaces model to create both, server and client applications. Unfortunately I got stuck on a problem with VsCode that is trying to resolve the `tsconfig.json` file to the root directory and not inside the project folder.

This is my structure:

```
project-root
├── .vscode
│   └── settings.json
├── client
│   ├── .eslintrc.js
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── src
│   │   └── App.tsx
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   └── yarn.lock
├── package.json
└── server
    └── ...
```

And here are the content of the above files.

---

`.vscode/settings.json`:

```js
{
    "javascript.validate.enable": false,
    "editor.tabSize": 4,
    "eslint.enable": true,
    "eslint.packageManager": "yarn",
    "eslint.codeActionsOnSave.mode": "all",
    "eslint.workingDirectories": [
        { "directory": "../server", "changeProcessCWD": true },
        { "directory": "../client", "changeProcessCWD": true }
    ],
}
```

---

`project-root/package.json`:

```js
{
  "name": "root-project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Rhuan Karlus Silva",
  "license": "MIT",
  "workspaces": {
    "packages": [
      "server",
      "client"
    ]
  }
}
```

---

`project-root/client/.eslintrc.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    env: {
        browser: true,
        es6: true,
        jest: true,
    },
    extends: [
        'react-app',
        'airbnb',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
        'prettier/@typescript-eslint',
    ],
    globals: {
        Atomics: 'readonly',
        SharedArrayBuffer: 'readonly',
    },
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaFeatures: {
            jsx: true,
        },
        ecmaVersion: 2018,
        sourceType: 'module',
        project: 'tsconfig.json',
    },
    plugins: ['react', 'import', 'jsx-a11y'],
    rules: {
        'react/jsx-filename-extension': [
            'error',
            {
                extensions: ['.tsx'],
            },
        ],
        "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility": "off",
        "indent": ["error", "tab"],
        "no-tabs": ["error", { allowIndentationTabs: true }],
        "react/jsx-indent": [2, 'tab', {
            checkAttributes: true,
            indentLogicalExpressions: true
        }]
    },
    settings: {
        'import/parsers': {
            '@typescript-eslint/parser': ['.ts', '.tsx'],
        },
        'import/resolver': {
            typescript: {},
        },
    },
};
```

---

`project-root/client/package.json`:

```js
{
  "name": "project-client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/core": "^10.0.28",
    "@emotion/styled": "^10.0.27",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "emotion-theming": "^10.0.27",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "typescript": "~3.7.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "../node_modules/.bin/eslint"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.33.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.33.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.0",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5"
  }
}
```

---

`project-root/client/tsconfig.json`:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

---

Alright now that I exposed the problem, I'm seeing two issues. Here are they:

1. Cannot find module 'react'.

[image: Cannot find module react]

2. tsconfig.json not found

[image: tsconfig.json not found]

Now please note that the second (tsconfig.json) error is showing the path to the `project-root` directory and not to the `project-root/client` directory as it should point.

So, am I figuring out something wrong? How can I solve this and get my workspaces working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright people, I've found a solution for the second problem and, thanks to @Daniel, I could solve the first problem too. And here's the complete answer:

First of all I did what @Daniel told me on his answer, I **removed** this lines from my `.vscode/settings.json` file:

```
"eslint.workingDirectories": [
    { "directory": "../server", "changeProcessCWD": true },
    { "directory": "../client", "changeProcessCWD": true }
],
```

And then, I created the file `project-root/.eslintrc.js` with this content:

```
module.exports = {
    "eslint.workingDirectories": [
      { directory: "./client/", changeProcessCWD: true },
      { directory: "./server/", changeProcessCWD: true },
    ],
};
```

This way the `Cannot find module 'react'` problem gone.

Now to the `tsconfig.json not found` problem, I don't know exactly why this worked since it have no precise meaning to me, but if it works, it works. I changed the `parserOption` inside my `project-root/client/.eslintrc.js` to this:

```
parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
        jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: 'module',
    project: './client/tsconfig.json',
},
```

Given that the `changeProcessCWD` flag is set, I didn't thought I would need to change this. But it worked. So, that's it.

Thanks everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem with a similar setup, the way I solved was to create a *.eslintrc.js* at the root directory and added this:

```
module.exports = {
  "eslint.workingDirectories": [
    { directory: "client/", changeProcessCWD: true },
    { directory: "server/", changeProcessCWD: true },
  ],
};
```

You should also remove the *eslint.workingDirectories* from *.vscode/settings.json*, or update it with the above code.

Hopefully this will do, you could also try to remove the *workspaces* from *project-root/package.json* if the above steps won't solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, it really solved the problem number 1: Cannot find module 'react'. Now this is working properly, but the tsconfig.json problem wasn't solved.

Comment: Could you check if the client will run in a terminal without any issues ? (even if vscode is showing you errors)


It could also be caused because of
` parserOptions: {
        project: 'tsconfig.json',
}
`
*in client/.eslintrc.js* - you could try to remove the *project* property specified above.


If the above solution doesn't work, it might be a vscode config or perhaps a .vscode folder in your project, you could try to remove all the .vscode folders in the project.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Alright, I solved the problem here, and I'll post the answer tonight (after 20:00 BRT) to give the chance to someone else to answer it fixing both problems. If no one else could find a solution I'll post here the solution I've found. :) think it's a good way of let other developers have the chance to win some good points for their effort :)